# How to avoid for-loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I guess this is a very usual question amongst R user, but stills not clear to me. I want to parse all the elements of column fnl3$aaa and for each of them perform a lookup in column df$aaa. If a match occurs, then append a numeric value at the end of a temp vector. My problem is that this process takes too long to complete. So I was wondering how I could meke it run faster. Any ideas?

```
cur <- c("")
for (i in 1:unq21) {
   prev <- cur
   for (j in 1:unq11) {
      if (cnt1$aaa[j] == fnl3$aaa[i]) {
         print('MATCH!!!')
         print(cnt1$freq[j])
         print(fnl3$V1[i])
         cur <- append(prev, as.vector(fnl3$V1[i] / cnt1$freq[j]), after = 0)
      }
   }
}
```

**SAMPLE DATASET:**

```
fnl3
    row.names   aaa                                    V1
1   404     1DC8F216-9138-4151-ABD6-36C3C2C75001        3
2   1533    638DF397-359E-43A5-A2F7-2C43CABA93DA        3
3   14      015ee60dbf299f5419eed89214b7409a            2
4   98      08CFF963-5565-4B8C-814E-FDFA5D37DCD6        2
5   488     226afbbac8dfd6f3c27cb16f9d7922a2            2

cnt1
    aaa                                         freq
1   000089f457881d57d4f221948c2b808c            1
2   00081dd2fd542a2a9c64a8990a1fc986601ab318    1
3   0021a8971f976743c2043b60e38eab46            1
4   0034d5d368611e33d7cfcda85df96eba            1
5   00379FA3-07A6-4AF7-ACBC-721E2E33DD67        1
```

Comment: Show us your data. The general process you're looking for is maybe something like `ifelse(fnl3$aaa %in% df$aaa, #do something#, #else something else#)`.

Comment: I quoted a sample dataset as well. can you have a looK?

Comment: What are `unq11` and `unq21`?

Comment: They are the length of column cnt1$aaa and fnl3$aaa respectively.

Comment: Please update your script accordingly to make it reproducible

Comment: Instead of your current data presentation, paste in the output from `dput(head(fnl3))` and `dput(head(cnt1))`. These things make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: the output is HUGE. I can't copy - paste all this stuff in here. what's not clear from the above?

Comment: Unfortunately, your example is not very representative as it does not contain any match between the two `aaa` columns...

Comment: Are any of `cnt1$aaa` duplicated? Are any `fnl3$aaa` duplicated? If not, then I think you could use: `c(na.omit(fnl3$V1/cnt1$freq[match(fnl3$aaa, cnt1$aaa)]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use `merge` to build a data.frame where the `aaa` columns match:

```
m <- merge(fnl3, cnt1, by = "aaa")
```

Then, you can compute that vector you were storing in `cur` by simply doing:

```
with(m, V1 / freq)
```

You can do it all in one call:

```
with(merge(fnl3, cnt1, by = "aaa"), V1 / freq)
```